# Not receiving notifications from Firebase in Android, but connection is established

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

### Versions

- @react-native-firebase/app: 6.3.4
- @react-native-firebase/messaging: 6.3.4
- react: 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.4

Inside my **App.js** file, I'm registering for notifications like this

```
...
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const registerForNotifications = async () => {
    const granted = await messaging().requestPermission();
    if (granted) {
      console.log('User granted messaging permissions!');
    } else {
      console.log('User declined messaging permissions :(');
    }
    await messaging().registerForRemoteNotifications();

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('FCM Message Data:', remoteMessage.data);
    });
    const token = await messaging().getToken();
    console.log({token});
    return unsubscribe;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    registerForNotifications();
  }, []);

  ...
}
```

and it shows me that user granted messaging permissions, and it seems to register correctly for remote notifications, and finally I get the token, which seems to be ok and connected.

In firebase messaging console, I send a new notification and in possible targets it seems to be my user (Inside **Cloud messaging** menu)

[image]

So I do not see any error, but for some reason I sent multiple notifications, and I don't receive them, it doesn't matter if the app is open or close. I don't know what to do because I cannot see any error.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any updates on this?